# Getting pixel positions for all points in a WPF Path

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas, bezier

Say you have a Bezier spline drawn on a canvas like so:

```
<Canvas x:Name="SomeCanvas" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Black">
    <Path x:Name="SomePath" Data="M0,0C10,10 10,50 50,10" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Canvas>
```

How would you determine which pixels in the canvas are intersected by the path's center (meaning stroke thickness is disregarded)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean you want to find the center point ***along*** the path. I think we have to do something with the Path's Data which is actually a `Geometry`. A `Geometry` has a method called `GetFlattenedGeometryPath` returning a `PathGeometry` which has a method called `GetPointAtFractionLength`. So you can try something like this:

```
 Point centerPoint;
 Point tg;
 SomePath.Data.GetFlattenedGeometryPath()
              .GetPointAtFractionLength(0.5, out centerPoint, out tg);
```

If you mean you want to find all the points, I think it's a little abstract on this problem. Technically there are an infinite number of points. So you can just such as find 1000 points evenly scattered along the path using the following code:

```
Point p;
Point tg;
var points = new List<Point>();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  SomePath.Data.GetFlattenedGeometryPath()
               .GetPointAtFractionLength(i / 1000f, out p, out tg);
  points.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: I did mean find all points and I do realize in vector-based drawing there are (technically) infinite points in a path. There must be a way to do it by sweeping all canvas' points and finding the ones that the path is on - although I would think in a larger Canvas this would be much more inefficient. However your solution is already very, and I repeat, very much what I was looking for! :D